# Find the $\Delta y$ of $f(x)={1 \over x^2}$; $x=2; \Delta x = 0.01$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, proof-verification, differential

Find the $\Delta y$ of $f(x)={1 \over x^2}$; $x=2; \Delta x = 0.01$

when $\Delta y = f(x+ \Delta x) - f(x)$

So here's what I did:

$$\Delta y = f(x+ \Delta x) - f(x) \\
\Delta y = {1 \over (x+ \Delta x)^2} - {1 \over x^2}\\
= {1 \over x^2+2x\Delta x +\Delta x^2} - {1 \over x^2}\\
={1 \over 2x\Delta x + \Delta x^2}$$
Now substituting x=2 and $\Delta x$=0.01

$${1\over 2(2)(0.01) + (0.01)^2}\\
={1\over 0.04+0.0001}\\
={1 \over 0.0401}\\
$$
I'm pretty sure there is something wrong I did. It says that the answer is supposed to be $$-0.00248$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b} \neq \frac{1}{a-b}$

Comment: Yes, I just realized that thank you!

Comment: Let us know if you come right.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this problem. Could you show me the steps please? @K.Power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything up to your 3rd step is fine. You could actually just sub in your values here but I'll show you how to properly manipulate fractions by getting them in terms of the LCD. So:
$${1 \over x^2+2x\Delta x +\Delta x^2} - {1 \over x^2}=\frac{x^2}{x^2(x^2+2x\Delta x +\Delta x^2)}-\frac{x^2+2x\Delta x +\Delta x^2}{x^2(x^2+2x\Delta x +\Delta x^2)}$$ $$=\frac{-(2x\Delta x+\Delta x^2)}{x^2(x^2+2x\Delta x +\Delta x^2)}$$
Now we substitute in our values:
$$\Delta y=\frac{-(4(0.01)+0.01^2)}{4(4+4(0.01)+0.01^2)}=-0.002488$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{1}{x^2+2x\triangle x +\triangle x^2} - \dfrac{1}{x^2} \neq \dfrac{1}{x^2 +2x\triangle x}$